# Entity Framework Join table or 1..*

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm making a database for my `asp.net mvc` site.

Here are 2 of my `models`:

```
public class Workout
{
    public Workout()
    {
        this.Sets = new List<Set>();
        this.Programs = new List<Program>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Set> Sets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Program> Programs { get; set; }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        this.Workouts = new List<Workout>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for `Program` to have 1 or more `Workouts`.

So when I create a `Program`, I have to give it `Workouts`, as it is now, the join table never comes.

any help appreciated.

Comment: I was expecting a join table of ProgramId's and WorkoutId's

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to fetch values? Are you sure that in the DB `Program` has corresponding `Workouts`? Can you show your mapping configuration?

Comment: You need to have a separate mapping table to store the records between Program and Workout. Example:

public class ProgramWorkout
{
      public int ProgramId {get; set;}
      public int WorkoutId {get; set;}
      
      [ForeignKey("ProgramId")]
      public virtual Program Program {get; set;}
      
      [ForeignKey("WorkoutId")]
      public virtual Workout Workout{get; set;}
}

A little rough solution, but hope you get the idea.

Comment: When you run a migration, the EF will automatically create a joining table for Program and Workout, unless you are using some custom mapping. Are you using some custom mapping? Could you show us?